# Implementing (not handling) CollectionChanged event

Tags: c#, .net

I have created a class that extends the base class `ListView.ColumnHeaderCollection` (found in `System.Windows.Forms`) and I want to be able to receive a notification of when the collection is changed via INotifyCollectionChanged.

So far, I have:

```
public class MyCollection : ListView.ColumnHeaderCollection, INotifyCollectionChanged { ... }
```

In my initialization method, I am assigning the delegate my own method `OnCollectionChanged()`.

```
UserSettings.Instance.Columns.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(OnCollectionChanged);
```

For those who are curious, my delegate looks like:

```
public void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Settings_Save();
}
```

And so we arrive at my problem. I don't know how to implement the interface member required by `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

```
'_Namespace_.MyCollection' does not implement interface member 'System.Collections.Specialized.INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged'
```

Many thanks from this C# newbie!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx), it requires a public event member called `CollectionChanged` to be in the implementing class. I.e:

```
public class MyCollection : INotifyCollectionChanged
{
    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
    // ...
}
```

EDIT: Overriding a non virtual property using the [`new`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) keyword:

```
public class MyListView : ListView
{

    public new MyCollection Columns { get; set; }
    //...

}
```

However you have to be careful. If a reference type refers to `ListView.Columns` it will be a different collection than `MyCollection.Columns` and cause unexpected behaviour. When using `new` to override a base property you should set/get the base property, this preserves the integrity of the collections, I.e:

```
public class MyListView : ListView
{
    public new MyCollection Columns
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Columns as MyCollection;
        }
        set
        {
            base.Columns = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Xenolightning! This isn't exactly obvious given the error I'm given.

Comment: Further question... I'm implementing a subclass of `ListView.ColumnHeaderCollection` (found in the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace) partly because I want to receive notification for `CollectionChanged()`, however, I am unable to override the property I intend (`ListView.ColumnCollection Columns`) because it's not defined as `virtual`. Is there an alternative to overriding the property to get the same desired effect?